# SWI-Prolog compare value from list with constant, but getting error character expected

Tags: prolog

I want to write a SWI-Prolog program, which tests if the result is lower than 4.0.

Therefore I pass a list like this `[Name, Subject, Result]`, the subject and the name for the return value.

```
third([Head|Tail], Z) :-
    Z = Tail.

second([Head|Tail], Z) :-
    Z = Head.

test([Head|Tail], Subject, Z) :-
    second(Tail, Subject2),
    Subject2==Subject,
    third(Tail,Result),
    Result=<4.0,
    Z=[Head|Tail].
```

Now if I execute with the following parameters:

```
test([smith, mu, 2.4], mu, R).
```

There is an error occuring:

```
ERROR: =</2: Type error: `character' expected, found `2.4'
```

I just can't find a way to fix it.

Comment: `test/3` could be simplified: `test([H, Subject, Result], Subject, [H, Subject, Result]) :- Result =< 4.0.` And since you're just giving back the first argument in the third argument on success, you could just omit the third argument: `test([_, Subject, Result], Subject) :- Result =< 4.0.` You don't need `second/2` or `third/2`.

Comment: `[Name, Subject, Result]` is an inefficient representation and prone to usage errors. If possible, use instead a term like `data(Name, Subject, Result)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `third(Tail,Result)` with `third(Tail,[Result])`:

```
test([Head|Tail], Subject, Z):-
    second(Tail, Subject2),
    Subject2==Subject,
    third(Tail,[Result]),
    Result =< 4.0,
    Z=[Head|Tail].
```